# How install the mbstring extension in Centos?

Tags: php, centos, multibyte

I get the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /var/www/html/dai/components/com_servicemanager/views/i0602/view.html.php on line 67

I create a file CSV as :

```
<?php

$dateTimeNow = ...

$list = $this->get('DataCSV'); 

$filename = 'CSV_' . $dateTimeNow . '.csv';

foreach ($list as $item)
{ 
    $csv .= join("\t", $item)."\r\n"; 
}  

$csv = chr(255) .chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($csv, "UTF-16LE", "UTF-8");


header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-disposition: csv; filename=$filename; size=" . strlen($csv));
echo $csv;
exit;
```

I run on wamp on Window is Ok. But i put on server is Centos, it can't create file csv. Why ? Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: Use http://php.net/fputcsv ...

Comment: Are you shure `$this->get('DataCSV')` Returns something?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your script, the you should see an error. This needs basic debugging first. Also please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools and reduce the code to a minimum to describe your problem. If you can only post your whole code, that is a sign that you need to look for error messages first as they contain a line number where a problem is.

Comment: it's show : Notice: Undefined variable: csv in /var/www/html/dai/components/com_servicemanager/views/i0602/view.html.php on line 64

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /var/www/html/dai/components/com_servicemanager/views/i0602/view.html.php on line 67

Comment: you need to enable mb_string extension in php

Comment: @ KingCrunch if i use fputcsv, file error font utf_8 when open with excel

Comment: @ GBD : how enable ms_string in centos 6.02 ?

Comment: Here is link which guide you http://tutorial.mooash.com/how-to-enable-mb_string-in-php/

Comment: I think the question title is misleading. Shouldn't it be something like: "How do I fix the 'Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding()' php error?"

Answer (score 6):

Turns out you have the `mb_string` function missing. Install it:

```
$ sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

That should fix the issue for you because it takes care installing the package.

For the undefined variable, you should see the same notice on windows as well when you enable error reporting.

Just initialize `$csv` before you add more to it:

```
$csv = '';
foreach ($list as $item)
{ 
    $csv .= join("\t", $item)."\r\n"; 
}
```

Comment: $ sudo yum install php-mbstring show error can't open/read file repomd.xml

Comment: @mum: Contact the system administrators of the server and tell them you need the mbstring package for PHP.

Comment: I create a server centos, so i am  system administrators.

Comment: The error you give is not the whole output when you get it. Add the command and all of it's output to your question, otherwise I can't help you any further.